# Как можно реализовать "пипетку" во Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Разобралась, как пользователю загрузить изображение, почитала про бинарное представление изображения, но вот как сделать именно чтобы человек "тыкнул" и получил усредненный цвет в радиусе, например, 10 пикселей, не понимаю. Во flutter разбираться только начала, с картинками работала в языке Си)))

Выбор изображения пользователем из галереи сделала так:

```
  File? image;
  Future pickImage() async {
    try {
      final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
      if (image == null) return;
      final imageTemp = File(image.path);
      setState(() => this.image = imageTemp);
    } on PlatformException catch(e) {
      print('Failed to pick image: $e');
    }
  }
...
MaterialButton(
              color: Colors.green,
              child: const Text('Pick image from gallery'),
              onPressed: () {
                pickImage();
              },
            ),
```